# Swift 2: Table view cellForRowAtIndexPath - BAD_EXEC

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview

I have a Problem with some code, that did actually work in xCode 6 (with ios 8.1), but does not with 7.1 (and ios 9.1).

I have a table view with a custom cell filled by Information from core data. In my test Szenario 1 entry is in coredata. In every cell i do a Count on another core data entity (representing the number of related entries on the next detailed view). In my testszenario this entity has no related entries.

Unfortunetly I get an error (unexpectly found Nil while unwrapping optional value) with xcode 7.1 an can't tell where it comes from.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UI_Buyer_My_Bubbles_Cell  
    if let buyers_bubbles = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Buyer_My_Bubbles {

        cell.label_seller?.text = buyers_bubbles.user_seller_name
        cell.label_points?.text = "\(buyers_bubbles.points_buyer_collected) bubbles"+"\r\n"+"gesammelt"
        cell.label_image?.image = UIImage(data:buyers_bubbles.user_seller_logo!)

        if ((buyers_bubbles.user_seller_no_devices=="1") || (cell.label_image.image == nil)) {
            cell.label_image?.image = UIImage(named: "no_logo")
        }

        //Count the number of offers
        var offer_count = 0

        do {

        let managedObjectContext2 = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Buyer_My_Offers")
        var error: NSError?
        let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext2!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Buyer_My_Offers]
        if let results = fetchedResults {
        if results.count==0{
            for (var i=0; i < results.count; i++)
                {
                    if (results[i].offer_seller_id == buyers_bubbles.user_seller_id) {
                        offer_count = offer_count + 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            if offer_count == 1 {
                cell.label_no_offers.text = "\(String(offer_count)) Prämie"
            }
            if offer_count == 0 {
                cell.label_no_offers.text = "Keine "+"\r\n"+"Prämien"
            }
            if offer_count > 1 {
                cell.label_no_offers.text = "\(String(offer_count)) Prämien"
            }

        }
catch {print("Unable to complete request. \(error)")}

   }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER do any fetchRequest inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath - because this will bring your application to hang (reloads always your data while scrolling).

Load your Results in ViewDidLoad, and refresh them when needed.

Like:

> ViewDidLoad:
>
> Load Core Data Objects
>
> Reload TableView

Comment: You're probalby right, but this is probably not the cause for the BAD_EXEC, is it?

Comment: It could be. Because fetchs are quite slow. And if there count if your objects in "NumberOfRowsInTableView" is not the same as your NSManagedObjectArray in cellForRowAtIndexPath - this would bring the same error. Ill think that is your problem, and i would start to fix that first.